# How to underline text in Android Studio?

Tags: android

Looked everywhere, couldnt find a solution for this. Setting bold or italic is very easy, why is setting underline not as easy?

Here's my bit of relevant code:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/forgotpasswordHolder"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forgot your password?"
            android:id="@+id/labForgotpassword"
            android:textColor="#6BB08C"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Not a member?"
            android:id="@+id/signup"
            android:textColor="#6BB08C"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have two "Forgot your password? and a "Not a member?" buttons, and I'd love it if I could underline the text(s).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Use a string resource with `<u>` tags, like this

```
android:text="@string/forgotPassword"
```

Then in strings.xml, create a String

```
<string name="forgotPassword"><u>Forgot your password?</u></string>
```

Comment: So I tried it out, but it doesn't underline. I even played around with the color of it, changing it android:textColor="#FFFFFF", which changed it to white, but still no underline.

Comment: It won't show up in the editor, but it should work once you run the app

Answer (score 2):

Just create a `View` below the `TextView`

As an example...

[image]

[image]